# Get .ajax results per post ID

Tags: ajax, jquery, each

On Tumblr, I've got several posts that I'm trying use .ajax to get data from specifically. I'm using an .each to only get data for audio posts. But the problem I'm running into is that it's returning all the posts, not just audio posts. I'm even specifying the json path for each specific post ID. I know I'm probably setting this up completely wrong as I'm not too familar with using .ajax.

```
$('.audio.post').each(function() {
    var audiopostID = $(this).attr('id');
    var audioPath = '/api/read/json?id=' + audiopostID;

    $.ajax({
        url: audioPath,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

As I mentioned, it returns all the posts, not the specific posts I'm trying to get with `audioPath`. The individual json paths do exist, it just seems the .ajax ignores the individual ones and grabs everything. Here's the first two audio post json paths:

- http://testrtheme.tumblr.com/api/read/json?id=46623753663
- http://testrtheme.tumblr.com/api/read/json?id=46483357977

Comment: Are you sure that audiopostID is populated? When I run that without an id specified it returns all the results.

Comment: Yeah. If I log it to the console, it returns all of the ID's for each audio post.

Comment: I mean before it gets to AJAX. Do an alert or write the audioPath to the console to make sure that the your URL looks like the one you specified in your question.

Comment: No problem. Here's all three console logs. http://cl.ly/NzIp - You'll see: audiopostID, audioPath, audiopostID, audioPath and then the two .ajax entries, which you can see are dumping all 17 posts in there.

Comment: I see a negative in front of the ID. That doesn't match what you displayed in your URLs and if I add a negative to the front of the post ID, it returns all the results.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27417/discussion-between-ryan-palmer-and-user1048676)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pulling the ID field from the following code:

```
<article class="post text brick" id="post-46308156089" data-postID="46308156089" data-permalink="http://testrtheme.tumblr.com/post/46308156089/test">
```

The id here is:

```
post-46308156089
```

Based on that you're URL looks like:

```
/api/read/json?id=post-46308156089
```

Try and change your code to the following:

```
$('.audio.post').each(function() {
var fullaudiopostID = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
var audiopostID = fullaudiopostID[1];
var audioPath = '/api/read/json?id=' + audiopostID;

$.ajax({
    url: audioPath,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
});
```